# str2double returning NaN MATLAB

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, double

I have a vector of rock types, in the form

```
Rock_1             '1' % What I get after use regexp%
Rock_2             '2' 
.                  . 
.      --------->  . 
.                  .
Rock_n             'n'
```

I'm interested in the number of the rock so I managed to get it using

```
Rocks = regexp(P(:,3),'\d*','Match')
```

Then I need to convert the cell array of numbers in a matrix of numbers, for statistical treatment. The problem is that after using `str2double` I get an array full of NaNs. I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Help please.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that the output from [`regexp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) is a cell array of cell arrays of strings (i.e. two levels of cell encapsulation), but you want it to be a cell array of strings. You can achieve that by adding the [`'once'` option](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#btn_p45-option) to the call to `regexp`. Then you will get a cell array of strings that can be passed to [`str2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html):

```
>> P = {'Rock_1', 'Rock_2', 'Rock_3'};  % Sample data
>> Rocks = regexp(P, '\d*', 'match');   % How you did it above
>> str2double(Rocks)

ans =

   NaN   NaN   NaN

>> Rocks = regexp(P, '\d*', 'match', 'once');  % With the 'once' option
>> str2double(Rocks)

ans =

     1     2     3
```